# Values inside multiple natural joins being skipped over

Tags: oracle

I'm working on a code to better format an output of something I have confirmed works using natural joins. The output I get (seen below) is almost perfect to the correct output I get using another code except it misses a value that's on the "inside" of the joins. I know this gets skipped over in the natural join method but I'm not sure on a way to get it to show.

Using the natural join code

```
    select * from

    (
    select * from
    ((select part_num, num as a0   from Parts where num = :asm0) 
    natural left join 
    (select part_num, num as a1   from Parts where num = :asm1)
    natural left join
    (select part_num,  num as a2 from Parts where num = :asm2)
    natural left join
    (select part_num,  num as a3 from Parts where num = :asm3))
    where a1 is null or a2 is null or a3 is null

    union

    select * from
    ((select part_num, num as a0   from Parts where num = :asm0) 
    natural right join 
    (select part_num, num as a1   from Parts where num = :asm1)
    natural right join
    (select part_num,  num as a2 from Parts where num = :asm2)
    natural right join
    (select part_num,  num as a3 from Parts where num = :asm3))
    where a0 is null
    )
```

I got the output

```
    Number            A0          A1            A2              A3
    351-2927-060                 944-3234-016   944-3234-212    944-3234-242
    351-2930-330    944-3234-010                944-3234-212    
    351-2930-430                **Should have 016 here**        944-3234-242   
    351-3487-344                                944-3234-212    944-3234-242
```

Using different code that I know returns the correct output I got

```
    Number          A's
    351-2927-060    944-3234-242
    351-2930-330    944-3234-010
    351-2930-330    944-3234-212
    351-2930-430    944-3234-016 shows the missing number
    351-2930-430    944-3234-242
    351-3487-344    944-3234-212
    351-3487-344    944-3234-242
```

Is there a way I can get this value to show using the natural join method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learned this recently but there is such a thing as Full join which would accomplish what I was trying to do.

```
select * from
(
(select part_num, num as a0   from Parts where num = :asm0) 
natural full join 
(select part_num, num as a1   from Parts where num = :asm1)
natural full join
(select part_num,  num as a2 from Parts where num = :asm2)
natural full join
(select part_num,  num as a3 from Parts where num = :asm3)
)
where a0 != any(a1,a2,a3) or a1 != any (a2,a3) or a2 != any(a3)
```